# Flatten dictionaries when a Keyerror Appears

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm flattening a nessted dict with this structure:

`[{'path': 'messageType', 'value': 'position'}, {'path': 'fcntup', 'value': 3320}]`

to have something like:

`{'messageType': 'position', 'fcntup': 3320}`

using this code:

`myDict= {x['path']: x['value'] for x in message['data']}`

however, sometimes, some of the dict dosen't has the key 'value', like:

`[{'path': 'messageType', 'value': 'position'}, {'path': 'fcntup', 'value': 3320},  {'path': 'deviceType'}, {'path': 'uplinkId'}]`

and when this happens, I got a KeyError and that doesn't allow me continue properly becasue i need to handle this and have a final dict like:

`{'messageType': 'position', 'fcntup': 3320, 'deviceType': null, 'uplinkId': null}`

Any idea how I could do this? I tried using a try-catch logic but doesn't works.

Thanks for the help

Comment: myDict= {x['path']: x.get('value') for x in message['data']}

Comment: What an easy way! new thing to understand! thanks a lot @Oleg!